# Where to keep additional functions in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to use a couple of my own functions in Laravel, but I don't want to `include` them in each file that will be using it. I guess there must be some place to store those things and load them when needed. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything in L4 docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself, although it wasn't *that* obvious :)

First, create a directory inside `app` (I called my `classes`). Then, inside, create a file (or files) and inside put your code. Remember, it has to be inside a class and your functions has to be both `public` and `static`, for example:

```
class Helpers {

    public static function getAvg($text){
        return $text;
    }

}
```

Then, edit `app/start/global.php` and look for a `ClassLoader::addDirectories` line. It is an array. At the end, add a line `app_path().'/{your_dir}',`, eg. `app_path().'/classes',`.

Comment: Correct, indeed. Though, I use `/adapters`, because it just sounds so much better. ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can also use Service  providers and Facade.

Comment: Well, let's be honest, creating new Package for three functions is kinda like shooting a fly with a cannon. But thanks for your advice anyway!

Comment: @TomekBuszewski True, but it is technically the standard and should be used if you will be having other Laravel 4-experienced developers working on your codebase.